# How to show a custom field instead of the_title

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a WordPress website and I want to show a list of all the posts in the current category (except the current post).

I need to use as anchor text the value of a specific `custom-field` named "test" instead of the post title.

How do I edit the code below in order to do that and excluding the current post?

```
    <?php
        global $post;
        $categories = get_the_category();
        foreach ($categories as $category) :?>
            <ul>
            <?php
                $posts = get_posts('numberposts=3&category='. $category->term_id);
                foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
<?php

global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();
$currentID = get_the_ID();
foreach ($categories as $category) :?>
  <ul>
      <?php
      $posts = get_posts('numberposts=3&category='. $category->term_id);
          foreach($posts as $post) : 
            if ( $currentID != $post->ID ) {
              ?>                 
                $test_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'test', true );
                ?>
                 <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                       <?php if ( ! empty( $test_value ) ) {echo $test_value; } else { echo 'Nothing'; } ?>
                    </a>
                 </li><?php
              } ?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that part. Updated.

Comment: that code has PHP syntax errors and it doesn't load :(

Comment: @danjah there are some problem with you code regarding closing of tags I have edited it please check  and  approve it.

Comment: customfield is correctly shown but I still see the current post in the list. I should exclude it.

Comment: Now it excludes one post, but the current post is still in the list.

Comment: @GingerGirl I've done another update now. If this doesn't work either, where have you placed your code?